# VS 2015 w/ Xamarin: This item does not support previewing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin 4.1.2.18 and CocosSharp PCL 1.6.2.

[image: About]

When I try to access the Properties of the Android project by clicking on the "Properties" item in the Solution Explorer, this error pops up:

[image: Properties]

[image: Invalid Pointer]

If I also right click on the project itself and select "Properties", it displays "This item does not support previewing".

It should be opening up to this page:

[image: Android Properties]

I have (supposedly) the latest build and Update 3. I have reinstalled it 3 times now.

1. Normal uninstaller. Reinstalled... nothing, still broken.
2. Uninstall again with cmd: /uninstall /force, use registry cleaners, manually uninstall components from Control Panel, manually delete folders. Reinstall... still broken.
3. Finally, I searched around and found this: [Microsoft Visual Studio Uninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases). After I, again, performed all the steps of 2, I used this tool and it found 52 additional things to clean up. I thought I finally had fixed it. Nope. The properties thing is still broken.

I have tried running as administrator. Nope.

I have deleted the ComponentModelCache in local AppData. Nope.

I have deleted the .suo file. Nope.

I know it has nothing to do with the project files because we have all the files synced with Git and my friend can view the properties page fine on his computer.

Does anybody know how I can fix this?
Is there some way to gather more information on the error?
Any Visual Studio error logs?

**Also, on an semi-unrelated note**:

When I try to build the Android project, I get errors saying that the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for my references/dependencies is v4.2 and the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) of my project is v2.3. I checked my TargetFrameworkVersion property in the .csproj file and it's v6.0!
So, something is seriously wrong with this build of Visual Studio or something.

I've been considering just installing Visual Studio on a VM just to be sure.

**Solution**:

In the Android SDK manager, I had Android 4.0 (API 14) downloaded. Once I switched to Android 4.2.2 (API 17) everything started working.

I just gotta say, the error that it gave me is the most convoluted error message that I've ever received in the history of my programming career.

Comment: 1) You try open VS2015 run as administator?
2) you try install Xamarin.Form in the aplication right click Nuget Manager. In your project

Comment: As stated in my post, I have already tried running VS as admin. My project doesn't utilize Xamarin.Form, so there is no need to install that. My friend can run the project fine without it. I have a feeling this is just a problem with my VS installation or there is a bug in the latest version of VS.

Comment: try to donwload the installer again. Is weird

Comment: I updated my post with the solution.